# Pandas, create new column based on values from previuos rows with certain values

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm trying to use ML to predict some future sales. So i would like to add mean sales from the previous month/year for each product

My df is something like: `[ id | year | month | product_id | sales ]` I would like to add `prev_month_mean_sale` and `prev_month_id_sale` columns

```
id | year | month | product_id | sales | prev_month_mean_sale | prev_month_id_sale
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2018 |   1   |    123     |   5   |         NaN          |    NaN          
2  | 2018 |   1   |    234     |   4   |         NaN          |    NaN
3  | 2018 |   1   |    345     |   2   |         NaN          |    NaN
4  | 2018 |   2   |    123     |   3   |         3.6          |     5 
5  | 2018 |   2   |    345     |   2   |         3.6          |     2 
6  | 2018 |   3   |    123     |   4   |         2.5          |     3 
7  | 2018 |   3   |    234     |   6   |         2.5          |     0 
8  | 2018 |   3   |    567     |   7   |         2.5          |     0 
9  | 2019 |   1   |    234     |   4   |         5.6          |     6 
10 | 2019 |   1   |    567     |   3   |         5.6          |     7
```

also I would like to add `prev_year_mean_sale` and `prev_year_id_sale`
`prev_month_mean_sale` is the mean of the total sales of the previuos month, eg: for month 2 is (5+4+2)/3

My actual code is something like:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():

   loc = df.index[(df['month'] == row['month']-1) & 
                  (df['year'] == row['year']) & 
                  (df['product_id'] == row['product_id']).tolist()[0]]

   df.loc[index, 'prev_month_id_sale'] = df.loc[ loc ,'sales']
```

but it is really slow and my df is really big. Maybe there is another option using `groupby()` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to avoid loop is to use `merge()` from dataframe:

```
df["prev_month"] = df["month"] - 1
result = df.merge(df.rename(columns={"sales", "prev_month_id"sale"}),
                  how="left",
                  left_on=["year", "prev_month", "product_id"],
                  right_on=["year", "month", "product_id"])
```

The `result` in this way will have more columns than you needed. You should `drop()` some of them and/or `rename()` some other.